# What is the uses of naming the route in Laravel 9?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-9

For example, this line exist in my web.php file. I just follow tutorials on Youtube, they did it like this.

```
// Show Login Form
Route::get('/login', [UserController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
```

So if I name the route, how could it benefits me?

Answer (score 1):

You can call this route with a helper method like this:

```
// Generating URLs for login page
$url = route('login');
 
// Generating Redirects to login page
return redirect()->route('login');
 
return to_route('login');
```

[Check to Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)

Comment: oookay, let say I didn't named the route, so how would I use it?